# How to store List of Bitmaps using ViewModel so as to survive Lifecycle changes?

Tags: android, bitmap, viewmodel, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

I am trying to store List of Bitmaps into **List** **<** **Bitmap** **>** after loading it from **InputStream** using the following code.

```
URL url = new URL(img_url);
            InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                trailerPicBitmaps.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream));
            }
```

So, Now after loading all the images using **AsyncTaskLoader** I am saving it in **List** **<** **Bitmap** **>** **bitmapList**. How to save this so as to surivie Configuration Changes. I used **onSaveInstanceState** butthe app crashes when I navigate to another app.

Is there anyway to do this using **ViewModel**?

Comment: Store it in a database, file

Comment: Actually I'm going to store it in Database only. But storing in will be users preference so I need to make it survive Configuration changes.

Comment: Than make your list static and store in that, later don't update the list just use it.

Comment: Using static doesn't work. I have tried it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so you can do it like this:

First of all place where you will keep your bitmaps (viewModel).

```
private val bitmapStore = MutableLiveData<List<Bitmap>>()
```

Now to get it you should use  (viewModel):

```
fun getBitmaps() = bitmapStore
```

In the fragment in `onActivityCreated` in e.g. `setupUi` place your observable:

```
viewModel.getBitmaps().observe(this, Observer { 
        //show bitmaps somewhere
    })
```

And to place bitmaps in your MutableLiveData (viewModel):

```
fun updateBitmaps(bitmaps:List<Bitmap>){
    bitmapStore.postValue(bitmaps)
}
```

If there will be some edits after placing it (that should change data before storing it in MutableLiveData) you should consider using `Transformations.switchMap`

`Update`
Example of receiving data from server (if you would like to store it in database you should check room and repository pattern).

```
fun fetchBitmaps(){
    apiServices.fetchBitmaps()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({
            updateBitmaps(it) 
        }, { throwable ->
            //on error
        })

}
```

Comment: Yes you can, just like normal use your apiServices, and in subscribe post your result to livedata that will call your observer.

Comment: Oh okay let me try this.
What's the diffference between LiveData and MutableLiveData ?

Comment: For things like this, please check documentation. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData